# SQL ServiceBrokerInterface transaction rollback not rolling back

Tags: sql-server, clr, service-broker

I'm doing some work with SQL service broker interface, I have a service associated with one queue and it contains only one method, the problem is when I receive the Message if I issue transaction.Rollback() the message disappear from the queue which I think shouldn't happen. Here is the method:

```
    [BrokerMethod("MySBResponseMessage")]
    public void ProcessRequestMessage(Message ReceivedMessage, SqlConnection conn, SqlTransaction trans)
    {
        trans.Rollback();
    }
```

and here is the service instance:

```
    service.Run(false, conn, null);
```

Thanks
mhashim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything should work..

Have you correctly implemented service class? And calling base class in constructor? like:

```
        class MyService : ServiceBrokerInterface.Service
        {
            public MyService(SqlConnection con)
                : base("ServiceName", con)
            {
                //...
            }

            [BrokerMethod("DEFAULT")]
            public void DoSmth(Message msg, SqlConnection con, SqlTransaction tran)
            {
                //...
            }
        }
```

Comment: yes I have, any way I was exploring the service broker interface for my next project and after digging deep into the implementation I came to the conclusion that its not production material. thanx anyway

Comment: So- what you will do- create your own interface? Or will not use Service Broker?

Comment: My friend service broker interface is is an example of how you could implement sql clr layer on top of service broker, as far as an example goes its fine but that's it.

Comment: As for your question what will I do? well I have already implemented my activation services in T-SQL and believe me it took a lot less time than the time  I spent looking through (service broker interface)